# Copying part of string and paste at the end in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of words like

```
one
two
three
```

in notepad++, how can I convert the words to strings like below at once:

```
<a href="function("one");"> one </a>
<a href="function("two");"> two </a>
<a href="function("three");"> three </a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expression placeholder can be used to repeat desired text.
For a single string match you can use find,replace like below

**Find:** `.*(one)`

**Replace** `<a href="function("\1");"> \1 </a>`

#### explanation:

**Find section :** In the above example all the text inside parenthesis `*(  )` will be copied to placeholder.

**Replace section :** wherever you want to replace the matched text, use \1, \2 etc. These are called placeholders

as of your example,

```
one
two 
three
```

In order to match every word you can use `(.+)` , ***but practically this may corrupt your data as it matches every word in the files***.

alternatively, you can define certain start & end characters to match the text.

For example, to match a text inside html tags, you can use `<(.*)>`
it matches

```
<one> → <a href="function("one");"> one </a>
<two> → <a href="function("two");"> two </a>
<three> → <a href="function("three");"> three </a>
```

Here in above example

> start character → `<`
> end character → `>`

you may replace with any character based on your requirement.

Comment: @gunr2171, replacing every word is practically won't workout. That's why I have answered considering a string based matching. Now, I have updated with pattern matching.

Answer (score 4):

Use regular expressions. Open the Find window and select the Replace tab. Activate regular expressions checkbox.

Find: `(.+)`
Replace: `<a href="function("\1");"> \1 </a>`

For more information, here is a tutorial:

http://markantoniou.blogspot.it/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html?m=1

Comment: Using the tips, I could acheive till
`<a href="funtion("one");">` but not able to add the word `one` repeatedly after this.

Comment: @Matteo, you should not copy the answer from other answers. It will be flagged for moderator attentions & you might face other consequences.

Comment: @Raju Actually I did not copy, the regular expression in the 'find' of Raju is not correct. Therefore I updated the answer with a correct version.    
BTW gunr2171 and Sadananda noticed the error too.

Comment: @Matteo, Initially you have provided only a tutorial link. Your answer came up only when I answered it. BTW, it's not error. Replacing every word is practically lead into big mistakes. Hence, I have provided pattern based matching.